# How to calculate distance from point to polygon with a time frame?

Tags: distance

Using the *Near* tool, I knew that I can just calculate the distance of each house to the nearest fire. However, I only want to keep fires that happened in the past 7 years for each house. For example, I have fire data from 1950 to 2013, a house was built in 2002. I only want to measure distance to the nearest fire from 1995 to 2002. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. Your question is very broad and you are not likely to get much in the way of answers. Try changing the question to provide more information about what what data you currently have and what format it is currently in.

Comment: It sounds like you may be using ArcGIS for Desktop but if you edit your question to state that and the version you are using then potential answerers will not need to make assumptions before deciding to help.

Comment: So you want a moving time window, ie the nearest fire within the seven years prior to *each* house's construction? I don't believe that can be done with a single tool. You'd need to build a model/script that would feed the Near tool a house and then a selection set of fires within the time frame, iterating through each house to do so. A more brute-force way would be to run Generate Near Table to get a matrix ranking the nearness of all fires to all houses, and then process that down using dates.